# VBA: Copying data to a worksheet that checks if record exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets, a pretty input worksheet for the end user to input data, and a data sheet to store the data after they enter it in. The input sheet has names in the first two columns (first and last) and has 2 or 3 columns after of data for that person. Right now my code takes all 5 columns, reads it into a dynamic array and writes it to the datasheet worksheet.
The amount of names in the input sheet can be added or subtracted at anytime. I want to know a way for excel to check if the names are already in the data sheet, and if they are just overwrite the data for that person. If that person doesn't exist then create a new line and copy the data over for that person.

Right now my code works by essentially copying the entire array, finding the next available row in the datasheet, and then writing the entire array there. The problem is that if I have 5 people, and I run my code to do this twice, I get two different instances of the same person. I can't just change my Range to activecell and overwrite it with the latest iteration of the input page because there are different grouping variables for the people. So when Group1 is selected on a different page, the input page is populated with only Group1 members, and then with Group2 etc. But I need to save them all to the same sheet.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
Dim BehvData() As Variant
Sheets("i_Behavior").Activate
BehvData = Range("A8", Range("A8").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4))
Worksheets("BehvDataSheet").Select
Range("A3").Select
Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown), ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(UBound(BehvData, 1) - 1, 4)).Value = BehvData
Erase BehvData
```

I'm very new to VBA and I appreciate your help here.

Comment: This looks a lot like a database, and not most suitable for excel.

Comment: Excel is a constraint that I can't get out of unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this perhaps work for you?

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NextAvailableRow As Long
    Dim ExistingDataRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("i_Behavior")
        For i = 8 To .Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
            If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BehvDataSheet").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                'EDIT: update only column E for existing value in column A
                ExistingDataRow = Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BehvDataSheet").Range("A:A"), 0)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BehvDataSheet").Range("E" & ExistingDataRow) = .Range("E" & i).Value
            Else
                NextAvailableRow = LastRow("BehvDataSheet", "A") + 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BehvDataSheet").Range("A" & NextAvailableRow & ":E" & NextAvailableRow) = .Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(SheetName As Variant, Col As Variant) As Long
    Application.Volatile True
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).Value <> "" Then
            LastRow = .Rows.Count
            Exit Function
        End If
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Yes actually! I was wondering if there was a way to keep the first four columns constant but overwrite the next one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Could you maybe give a little a little more detail about what you'd like it to do?  Is it that you want to overwrite only column E if the name is already on the list?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Basically since the first four columns are constant, fixed data like name id number etc. but the last column is user entered data that might be changed by the user.

Comment: I edited the code in my answer above to update only column E if the name is already on the list.  Can you give this a try?

Comment: It works perfectly, just so I can understand this a bit better can you explain how the first IF statement works. (Line 6)

Comment: I'm glad it's working.  I'll try to explain it from the inside out. The `match` part of that formula looks to see if the name already exists on the 2nd sheet in column A.  If it does find the name, `match` brings back the `row number` where it found it.  On the other hand, if the `match` doesn't find the name, then it returns an `error` instead of a `row number`. The `isnumber` part of the formula evaluates to `true` if the `match` brings back a `number`.  If the `match` brings back an `error` instead of a `number`, the `isnumber` part returns `false` so it knows to add that name to the list.

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer `ACCEPTED` if it is working for you? I could use the Rep Points. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much This has been very helpful in my learning. I pressed the green check box next to the answer? Is that accepting it? Thanks again!